# How do I activate full screen mode when using Skype?

Tags: skype, fullscreen

I'm using the version of Skype from the Ubuntu Software Centre (skype 2.2.0.35-0precise3) but I can't for the life of me see how to make a video call full screen. All I have is a small window, dragging to the edges of the screen doesn't 'aero-snap' it larger.

Am I missing something really obvious, I can't see any full screen button, or work out a keyboard shortcut. Is it even possible to have a full screen video call?

Comment: I am not sitting in front of my Ubuntu machine, but for sure it is possible and there is a full screen button

Comment: Have you tried pressing F11, the keyboard shortcut for fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was being a bit blind! When you are in a video call click the blue video button and select Full Screen. The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>F</kbd>

None of the commonly used fullscreen keyboard shortcuts for other applications work (like <kbd>F11</kbd>) Also the full screen option is not available when using the test call function which explains why I was struggling to find the option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Double-click into the video window. This should do it! (As it commonly does with many video players.)